# Cursor move to position is not in sync

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-cursor

I have a cursor, loaded during onCreate of Service. I have a getter for the cursor.

When it's time to move the cursor to a position, I call,

```
Log.e(TAG, "try moving to pos " + String.valueOf(position));
if(getCursor().moveToPosition(position)){
    setCursorPosition();
    if(getCursorPosition() == getCursor().getPosition())
        Log.e(TAG,"\t\t Moved to position \t\t");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(intentAction));
}
```

In Broadcst receiver, i receive the broadcast, and manipulate the cursor to update some UI elements

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction() == intentAction){
            Log.e(TAG,"currentTitlefrom cursor:"+MyService.getCursor().getPosition()+": :"+currentTitle);
            ... //ui updates here
            }
        }
```

In Log, i see

```
08-13 03:10:10.920: E/MyService(19548): try moving to pos 3
08-13 03:10:10.940: E/MyService(19548):         Moved to postion    
08-13 03:10:24.620: E/MainActivity(19548): currentTitlefrom cursor:2: :American Woman
```

Actually, the actual cursor is moved to position i wanted. I am sure of it because my service works as expected. but the main activity reports the only previous position, i.e.,the change is not synchronously reflected .

How to solve this??

**Note: 1** getCursor is a static function returning a static `Cursor` element

**Note: 2** MyService runs on Main UI Thread, not on different thread. Hence both `getCursor().moveToPosition(position)` and `MyService.getCursor().getPosition()` runs on UI thread only.

---

**EDIT** : My app model is

> UI never changes cursor position, it just reads the cursor

Answer (score 0):

pass cursor position in intent extra.So change your

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(intentAction))
```

to

```
 Intent in = new Intent(intentAction);
 in.putExtra("cursorPosition", position);
 sendBroadcast(in);
```

and receive in broadcast `onReceive` method as

```
if(intent.getAction() == intentAction){
int cursorPosition = intent.getIntExtra("cursorPosition", 0);
            Log.e(TAG,"currentTitlefrom cursor:" String.valueOf(cursorPosition ) +": :"+currentTitle);
            ... //ui updates here
            }
```

Comment: It's not about Logging the cursor position, it's then i'm using the cursor to get some column data,

Comment: @nmxprime get postion using intent extra and then get cursor element from **cursorPosition**